# Two y-axes ticks for one set of data, aligning both sets of ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have managed to plot y axis tick on the right as a percentage, but the labels aren't to appealing I want to change them to multiples of 10. How do I change the ticks so that they're 10^2% (100%), 10^1%, 10^0%, etc., but that they still match the ticks on the left?

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from numpy import nan, arange
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
import sys

twentytwo = {}
twentytwo[60.0] = [578, 85, 14, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

totNEA2014 = 1266

def to_percent(y, position):
    # Ignore the passed in position. This has the effect of scaling the default
    # tick locations.
    s = str(100 * (y/totNEA2014))
    if matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] == True:
        return s + r'$\%$'
    else:
        return s + '%'

# Plot Details
bar_width = 0.18
line_width = 1
opacity = 1.
centre_bar_positions = arange(20)
zeros = [0 for k in range(len(centre_bar_positions))]

# Make bar plots
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[12, 9])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
bar_60_22 = plt.bar(centre_bar_positions, twentytwo[60.0], bar_width, bottom=10**-1, alpha=opacity, color='green', log=True, label='V < 22')

plt.title("Some Place")
plt.ylabel("Number of NEAs")
plt.xlabel("Number of apparitions")
ax1.set_ylim([ax1.set_ylim()[0], totNEA2014])
ax1.set_yscale("log")
plt.legend(loc='best')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
plt.bar(centre_bar_positions, zeros, bar_width, bottom=10**-1, color='white', edgecolor='grey', linewidth=line_width, hatch='0', log=True)
ax2.set_ylim([ax1.set_ylim()[0], ax1.set_ylim()[1]])
formatter = FuncFormatter(to_percent)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.ylabel("Percentage of NEAs discovered in 2014")

plt.xlim([.6, 5.8])
plt.show()
```

This is what my code currently produces (I reduced the no. of bars in the code above):
[image]

Comment: is the desired output a right axis with values 10%, 100%, 1000%, 10000%, 100000%?

Comment: I want the right axis to have the values 0.01%, 0.1%, 1%, 10% and 100%

Comment: I think your code does already that if you set `totNEA2014 = 1000`

Comment: But I can't just change that, that is the total number of objects. I think I need to move the positions of the ticks on the right somehow

Comment: what i mean is that this number defines your axis formatting ... since you can write what you want on the axis, you could change the line `s = str(100 * (y/totNEA2014))` to `s = str(y/10)`

Comment: in other words, the numbers you got on the right are created by `s = str(100 * (y/totNEA2014))`. If you want these numbers to change, you should change that line. Unless, I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: @JulienSpronck But at the moment the scale of the axis on the right is correct, it is just not neat. I get that changing `totNEA2014` to 1000 would make the ticks display the right value but then they would be in the wrong place.

For example if I had a bar where the number of NEAs is 126.6 that is 10% of the total number of NEAs, but if I were to set `totNEA2014 = 1000` this would change the percentage to 12.66%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand. You want the right axis to go from 0 to 100% and be in log scale. I think this should do the trick.

```
totNEA2014 = 1266

def to_percent(y, position):
    # Ignore the passed in position. This has the effect of scaling the default
    # tick locations.
    s = str(100 * y)
    if matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] == True:
        return s + r'$\%$'
    else:
        return s + '%'

# Plot Details
bar_width = 0.18
line_width = 1
opacity = 1.
centre_bar_positions = arange(20)
zeros = [0 for k in range(len(centre_bar_positions))]

# Make bar plots
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[12, 9])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
bar_60_22 = plt.bar(centre_bar_positions, twentytwo[60.0], bar_width, bottom=10**-1, alpha=opacity, color='green', log=True, label='V < 22')

plt.title("Some Place")
plt.ylabel("Number of NEAs")
plt.xlabel("Number of apparitions")
ax1.set_ylim([ax1.set_ylim()[0], totNEA2014])
ax1.set_yscale("log")
plt.legend(loc='best')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
ax2.set_yscale("log")
ax1.bar(centre_bar_positions, zeros, bar_width, bottom=10**-1, color='white', edgecolor='grey', linewidth=line_width, hatch='0', log=True)
ax2.set_ylim([0.0001, 1])
ax2.set_yticks([0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.])
formatter = FuncFormatter(to_percent)
ax2.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.ylabel("Percentage of NEAs discovered in 2014")

plt.xlim([.6, 5.8])
plt.show()
```

Note that I changed your formatter function and also the plotting line (now only plotting to ax1 and not both axes)

Answer (score 0):

Like @julien-spronck, I may not be understanding what you need/what your plot means, but I agree about where I would fix it. If you just want to display the same number in a different format (percentages on the right, log scale of percentages(?) on the left), then

```
s = str(totNEA2014 * (y/totNEA2014))
```

yields: 
[image]

am puzzled by: left yaxis goes down to 0.1, but is labeled by "Number of NEAs"; do NEAs really come in counts less-than-one? Would you rather have a left yaxis with counts, 0-lots, and a right yaxis that's percentages and doesn't start at 0?

Comment: The left y-axis going down to 0.1 was another problem I had, it got errors when I tried to start the axis at 0. Ideally, I would like the left y-axis to display the number of NEAs which ranges from 0 to 1266 and the right y-axis to show the percentage. But I want to move the ticks I guess, so that the numbers are 100%, 10%, 1%, .1% (If I could get this to go to 0 too that would be great!). I hope that makes my problem clearer.

Comment: Well, log(0) is going to be perplex the formatter, that's true.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an extra axis with `.add_artist(matplotlib.axis.YAxis(ax1))` is more robust than using `.twinx()`.

Adding an extras *Axes* object with `.twinx()` seems overkill when all you need is an extra *axis*. Using `.twinx()` as proposed in the question also has the disadvantage that the second axis is decoupled from the data, so you need some hack to make it correspond to the data and the other axis, such as changing `ylim` (done in various ways in the other answers) -- however, this will break as soon as you change `ylim` on the original axis.

See below. I changed the first line in the `to_percent` function to get pretty number formatting and the block called "ADD SECOND Y-AXIS".

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from numpy import nan, arange
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
import sys

twentytwo = {}
twentytwo[60.0] = [578, 85, 14, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

totNEA2014 = 1266

def to_percent(y, position):
    # Ignore the passed in position. This has the effect of scaling the default
    # tick locations.
    s = '%g' % (100 * (y/totNEA2014))
    if matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] == True:
        return s + r'$\%$'
    else:
        return s + '%'

# Plot Details
bar_width = 0.18
line_width = 1
opacity = 1.
centre_bar_positions = arange(20)
zeros = [0 for k in range(len(centre_bar_positions))]

# Make bar plots
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[12, 9])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
bar_60_22 = plt.bar(centre_bar_positions, twentytwo[60.0], bar_width, bottom=10**-1, alpha=opacity, color='green', log=True, label='V < 22')

plt.title("Some Place")
plt.ylabel("Number of NEAs")
plt.xlabel("Number of apparitions")
ax1.set_ylim([ax1.set_ylim()[0], totNEA2014])
ax1.set_yscale("log")
plt.legend(loc='best')

# ADD SECOND Y-AXIS    
extra_axis = matplotlib.axis.YAxis(ax1)
extra_axis.tick_right()
formatter = FuncFormatter(to_percent)
extra_axis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
extra_axis.set_ticks([totNEA2014*10**p for p in range(-4, 1)])
extra_axis.set_label_text("Percentage of NEAs discovered in 2014")
extra_axis.set_label_position('right')
ax1.add_artist(extra_axis)

plt.xlim([.6, 5.8])
plt.show()
```